# Bitcoin Full Node Stalled - 13.2

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

A full node that I've had running for months just began to stall on a certain block. It seems to be refusing to update blocks beyond a certain timeframe. There are no processes spinning, network connection seems fine. I'm not sure where to check next...

Comment: Are you storing your blockchain data on an external drive?

Comment: No, just using a little bitseed box. Everything worked fine for months, it just started stalling out, and attempts to force a blockchain rebuild don't seem to work. I may have to just reimage the drive.

Comment: Is it on an SD card? I used to have a RaspberryPi to run Bitcoin Core and stored on the SD card. The SD card got corrupted pretty quickly. They're just not made to have that much I/O.